# Добавление новых данных в DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dict

Есть такой код

```
a = {'a': [1, 3, 4], "b": [1, 1, 1]}

b = {'b': 1, 'c': 3}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Как к существующему DataFrame добавить новый словарь и получить:

```
a  | b | c
==========
1  | 1 | NaN
3  | 1 | NaN
4  | 1 | NaN
NaN| 1 | 3
```

Т.е. я добавляю новый словарь, который может содержать ключи, которых ранее не было, и мне надо на новую строчку добавить все данные из нового словаря. Вместо NaN можно и просто пустоту, или 0

**Вопрос:** *как лаконично это можно сделать?*

Comment: df.append(b, ignore_index=True) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [19]: df = df.append(b, ignore_index=True)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  3.0  1.0  NaN
2  4.0  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  1.0  3.0
```